# Кодировка пути файла

Tags: java, charset

Приветствую всех!

Подскажите, как получить правильный путь файла?
Передаю в аргументах ссылку на файл с таким именем:

> GovHK 香港政府一站通：Homepage (Residents).webloc

А вместо имени получаю следующее:

> GovHK ???????:Homepage (Residents).webloc

Соответственно `file.exists();` выводит false;

На сколько я нарыл в интернете, это ISO-8859-10 и Java не поддерживает ее. Готовое решение по декодированию строки не нашел, так что обращаюсь к Вам.

Заранее спасибо!

**UPD**
Состряпал простой эквивалент кода:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            File file = new File(args[0]);
            System.out.println("Exists: " + file.exists());
        }
    }
}
```

А файл залил вот сюда: [file](https://github.com/benchdoos/benchdoos.github.io/raw/master/GovHK%20%E9%A6%99%E6%B8%AF%E6%94%BF%E5%BA%9C%E4%B8%80%E7%AB%99%E9%80%9A%EF%BC%9AHomepage%20(Residents).webloc)

Comment: Только что проверил: создал файл с именем, как указано `D:\\GovHK 香港政府一站通：Homepage (Residents).webloc` и вернул true. Может имеет смысл еще и Ваш код прикрепить, а может быть даже и файл, чтобы исключить неточности?

Comment: @MikitaBerazouski Добавил

Comment: Только что проверил - работает. А покажите как вызываете программу и как передаете параметры.

Comment: @MikitaBerazouski Передаю параметры таким образом:
`java -jar F:\Developer\JAVA\WeblocOpener\out\artifacts\test\test.jar "C:\Users\doos\Desktop\GovHK 香港政府一站通：Homepage (Residents).webloc"`
У Вас кстати какая OS? Просто сам файл был создан на MacOS, а открывать пытаюсь на Windows.

Comment: Проблема не в программе, а в windows консоли, которая переводит знаки в вопросы.

Comment: @MikitaBerazouski Есть ли способ достать оригинальное имя файла? Чтоб хотя-бы его переименовать в нормальный вид и все-таки обработать в приложении. Есть какие-либо идеи? Пробовал с программы через `Runtime` сделать переименовывание, но тщетно.

Comment: Ну все корректно работает через intellij idea. А так сейчас сам смотрю, если что-то найду - отпишусь.

Comment: Погодите, а что значит достать? У Вас же файл есть - Вы его прикрепили. Или Вы имеете в виду программно переименовать?

Comment: Есть решение, сейчас запилю.

Comment: Нет, все-таки не получилось. Думал через unicode символы.

Comment: @MikitaBerazouski Да, самое забавное - при переборе существующих файлов - отображается все корректно. А вот если передавать в качестве параметра - теряется исходное название файла. Пробовал вот такую штуку добавлять - `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` , но что-то не особо помогло.. вероятно кодировка не та...

Comment: Задал вопрос тоже [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082954/how-to-pass-hieroglyphs-as-an-argument-to-the-main-method-from-command-line), посмотрим, что скажут. Еще в русском сообществе тоже спрошу - интересно же =)

Comment: а какой это язык известно?

Comment: @MikitaBerazouski Это ссылка на сайт [Гонконга](https://www.gov.hk/tc/residents/), китайский (я думаю), словарь -  繁.
Вот ссылка на ту-же самую английскую страницу сайта: [ссылка](https://www.gov.hk/en/residents/)

Comment: @MikitaBerazouski "Евгений_Зражевский_@bench_doos.webloc" `//this 'й' contains 2 symbols: и and ̆ that crashes file.exists();`
Вот еще пример, с которым не могу разобраться... При чем (например notepad++) спокойно находит файл, а значит проблема в принятии аргумента... Аргумент принимаю через реестр при помощи shell/command "path_to_exe" "%1", так же принимает и notepad++, но он файл спокойно находит, а вот моя аппликуха теряет его... С cmd если передавать этот файл - все нормально работает... дилемма уже который день...

Comment: что-то не могу понять комментарий =) Первое - это ошибка? `this 'й' contains 2 symbols: и and ̆ that crashes file.exists();`

Comment: нет... получается как я разобрал строку там й состоит из и и знака (галочки сверху, не  получилось сейчас нормально скопировать - смотри в моем или своем пересланом комментарии перед словом that) когда вместе стоят - получается сливаются в й...

Answer (score 1):

Как и писалось выше проблема заключается в кодировке консоли, а не в самом приложении.
Для того, чтобы корректно поменять кодировки консоли часто хватает выполнить `chcp` команду, например, для UTF8 - это `chcp 65001`. Но в Вашем конкретном случае этого буде недостаточно. По сути Вам необходима кодировка 936. Однако если Вы выполните команду `chcp 936` Вы увидите сообщение `Invalide code page`. Чтобы избавиться от этого, Вам необходимо поменять регион. Для этого сделайте следующие шаги:

1. Пуск - Панель управления
2. Выбираем "Region and Language"
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Далее переходим на вкладку "Administrative" и выбираем "Change system locale"
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. В выпадающем списке выбираем "Chinese (Simplified, RPC)"
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
5. Перезагружаем компьютер

> Это не приведен к изменению интерфейса всей операционной системы.

После этого при запуске команды `chcp` вывод будет `Active code page: 936`. Теперь Вы можете запускать свое приложение - результат будет `true`:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вроде это как раз то, что Вы ищите.